# How to embed Twitter widget to Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

Going to the twitter widget site (https://publish.twitter.com/) I am able to get a widget to add to my site. I am using the sample code to try to understand hot it works:

```
<a class="twitter-grid" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/timelines/539487832448843776">National Park Tweets</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

If I just add this to an HTML page then the code works exactly as it should. It shows the grid with the respective tweets.

However, when adding this to ReactJS all I see is the fallback code, which merely provides a link to the twitter username.

I have tried using the following to no avail:

```
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: "<a className='twitter-grid' href='https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/timelines/539487832448843776'>National Park Tweets</a> <script async src='https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' charset='utf-8'></script>"}}>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out this npm package: [**react-twitter-widgets**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-twitter-widgets). This seems to be accomplishing what you need out of box.

```
import { Tweet } from 'react-twitter-widgets'

ReactDOM.render(<Tweet tweetId='511181794914627584'/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: This is all very well. But I'm not running this on a node environment.

Comment: Are you not using npm to manage your React packages too? it doesn't have to be run in the server.

Comment: This is all on a static html file, which I plan to put on codepen.

Comment: Yeah you're going to run into some complications with that approach (in the sense of finding help online/tutorials/etc)... best bet is you keep a src folder and use CommonJS/ES6 components to build you app locally and then use webpack to bundle it into a nice js file to upload to codepen. How complex is your app? At a certain point, React might not even be efficient for what you need.

Comment: If the OP only needs embedding, [react-tweet-embed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tweet-embed) is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if other people are still having this problem, but in my situation I was getting article body content from an API and simply inserting that html into a div and couldn't get the tweets to work properly.

Just figured out a solution though, so I have the widgets js in my index.html.

Then on component update I check that my article content has loaded then simply call `twttr.widgets.load()`

Here is my componentDidUpdate function:

```
componentDidUpdate(props) {
      if(this.props.article.status === 'FULFILLED' && this.props.article.status !== props.article.status) {
        twttr.widgets.load(
          document.getElementById('article')
        )
      }
    }
```

Hope someone else finds this useful!

Comment: Hey :) how/where did you implement the `twttr` function?

Comment: It was a long time ago, but IIRC I was using the twitter JS library. I don't have access to the code as I've changed jobs a couple of times since. I'm sure there are plenty of twitter libs now that you can use though.

Answer (score 2):

I was having issues with the twttr.widgets.load() method displaying the Tweet text before adding the styling. This is how I solved that with the twttr.widgets.createTweet() method and adding a loading state.

(Also using TypeScript & Tailwind CSS - feel free to remove that as needed.)

Add script to inside body in index.html:

```
<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script> 
</body>
```

Create Tweet component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Tweet({
  tweetID,
}: TweetProps) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if ((window as any).twttr) {
      (window as any).twttr.widgets.createTweet(
        tweetID,
        document.getElementById(tweetID),
        {
          align: 'center',
          conversation: 'none',
          dnt: true,
          theme: 'dark',
        }
      ).then(() => setIsLoading(false));
    };
  }, [tweetID]);

  return (
    <div className="w-full animate-fadeIn" id={tweetID}>
      {isLoading && <p>LOADING</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

interface TweetProps {
  tweetID: string,
};

// twttr.widgets.createTweet:
// https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/guides/embedded-tweet-javascript-factory-function

// Embedded Tweet parameter reference
// https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/guides/embedded-tweet-parameter-reference
```

Usage:

```
  <Tweet tweetID="1002103497725173760" />
```