# Cannot install react-twitter-embed

Tags: reactjs, npm, installation, npm-install

I want to use react-twitter-embed, but when I run the command this error appeares:
[install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O7P3.png)

If you know how to solve this problem please tell me.

Comment: From the error, it seems the react-twitter-ember depends on react 15 or 16 but your project has react 17. And thus the error. https://github.com/saurabhnemade/react-twitter-embed/blob/master/package.json#L39

Comment: you can refer this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874121/how-to-embed-twitter-widget-to-reactjs

Comment: Can I downgrade my project ?

Comment: New versions are supported now.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing that you have React 17 and you need React 15 or 16 version try both then see which one works.